# I could not insert form data into my table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I have a controller file where I get the values from my form.This is my controller function where I get my form data.

```
public function get_schedule_time()
    {
        $id=$this->uri->segment(4);
         if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_time', 'start_time');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('end_time', 'end_time');

            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                     'id' => $id,
                    'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time'),
                    'end_time' => $this->input->post('end_time')
                    );

                    if($this->schedule_model->store_schedule($data_to_store)){
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
                    }
            }
        }
        $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/schedule/get_schedule_time';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
```

I have a model file where I have written a query to insert form data.This is my function in model

```
 function store_schedule($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('schedule', $data);
        return $insert;

    }
```

I have a view file where I input my form data.

```
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_designation = array('' => "Select");

      echo validation_errors();

      echo form_open('admin/schedule/get_schedule_time', $attributes);

      ?>
    <div id="inputwrap">  
    <label>Employee Id</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$id?>" />
     </div> 
     <div id="inputwrap">
     <label>Start Time</label>
     <input type="time" name="start_time" value="<?php echo set_value('start_time');?>"/>AM
     </div>
     <div id="inputwrap">
     <label>End Time</label>
     <input type="time" name="end_time" value="<?php echo set_value('end_time');?>"/>PM
     </div>
     <div id="inputwrap">
     <button id="btn" type="submit">SAVE</button>
            <button id="btn" type="reset">CANCEL</button>
     </div>
        </fieldset>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Can someone help me code?

Comment: What is your controller **admin** or **schedule**?

Comment: schedule is my admin. admin/schedule/get_schedule_time calls the get_schedule_time function in my controller page @Chayan

Comment: Are you sure? Do you set proper routing for this?

Comment: Yes I am sure about it.I am confused here  $data_to_store = array(
                     'id' => $id);} At this place I get the id from uri segment

Comment: Is the time in your DB of type string/char or time?

Comment: Yes.TIME data type is what I have.

Comment: Your `$id` variable not assign data. So it will get fail. And in controller uri segment not work it out

Comment: strore the `id` value in hidden field and get `id` data by using `$this->input->post('the_id')`, `$this->uri->segment()` will not work here

Comment: How to POST the id value? @Abdulla

Comment: @Anu you have two controller names in your fom

Comment: 'id' => $id, cant this be done? @Abdulla

Comment: `<?=$id?>` what this do in your view ??

Comment: I pass id value form controller to my view. I kept that value in textbox. now I need to post that id value

Comment: use `<?php echo $id ?>`

Comment: No. After using this still I am getting a white screen